# How do i unit test the following lock and multi-threaded code

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, jmock

I have the following write method which writes data to a file using gson.

```
private static final File CONFIG_FILE = new File("./config.json");; 
private static final ReadWriteLock READ_WRITE_LOCK = new ReentrantReadWriteLock(true);
private static final Lock READ_LOCK = READ_WRITE_LOCK.readLock();
private static final Lock WRITE_LOCK = READ_WRITE_LOCK.writeLock();
...
    public void write(JsonData data) {
    Verifier.verifyNotNull(data,"data : null");
    Verifier.verifyNotNull(data.getData(),"JsonData data : null");
    Verifier.verifyNotEmpty(data.getIdentifier(),"JsonData identifier : empty");

    Writer writer  = null;
    Gson gson = null;
      try {  
         WRITE_LOCK.lock();
         writer = new FileWriter(CONFIG_FILE);

         gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
         gson.toJson(data, writer);
      } 
      catch (IOException e) {  
           e.printStackTrace();  
      }  
      finally {
         try {
             if (writer != null) {
                 writer.flush();
                 writer.close();
             }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
       catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
        finally {
           WRITE_LOCK.unlock();
        }
      }
```

The lock displayed above is Reeentrant lock provided by the Java libraries. If I want to unit test the above method for thread safety, how do it test it?

Please advise,

Thanks!

Comment: You need multiple try blocks for this. If `writer.flush()` throws an exception, you won't release the lock.

Comment: Hello, thanks for noticing that. I moved the 'writer.flush()' to the catch block. Since both '.flush' and '.close' methods throw 'IOExceptions', I am thinking the lock will be released in the catch block for 'IOException' shown above. Edited the code

Comment: Try nesting your try blocks so you have the outer one devoted to only the lock. This avoids having to call unlock in different places or being surprised by a bug in `flush()` throwing a `RuntimeException` that you missed.

Comment: How about if I just move the release lock to the finally block. Then catch the IOException and RuntimeException for both close and flush in the above code (without having to nest try-catches). Edited the code. Will that work?

Comment: If you do not state the specification of the code, nobody can suggest how to test the code meets that specification.

Answer (score 1):

If you inject either the `Writer` or the `Gson` object, you can provide a mock implementation. If you mock the writer, make the `write` methods block so they don't finish and release the lock. Do that in one thread. In another, call *your* `write` method again. Finally, in your "main" test thread, spin until the state of the blocked thread is `Thread.State.BLOCKED`. If it's never blocked or it finishes, you fail. Once you see that it's blocked, release the first thread (`CountDownLatch` is good for this), and verify that both threads finish.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am looking at Blitzer clas provided by Jmock. Will that also be enough? http://www.jmock.org/threading-blitzer.html

Comment: It depends on why you're locking. If it's because Gson isn't thread-safe, then probably. If it's because you don't want to write to the file concurrently, it depends more on your OS and file locking.

Comment: I am locking so that only one thread should be able to write at a time. reader-writer problem basically. This is a config file, so i don't want multiple threads to contend for writing into it.

Comment: One way to avoid this problem is have a single thread be responsible for writing the config file, then other threads queue up their changes. Message passing is a good trick for making things thread safe.